# Accessing Azure Ad Enterprise app without Assigning

Tags: azure, active-directory, single-sign-on, openid, saml-2.0

I Created new Azure AD with free trial subscription, and i have added applications from gallery and also created custom web app. And i am authenticating web app with OpenId connect and able to get access and refresh tokens.

As part of validations i just assigned app to only particular user and is get authenticated and redirected to the app and when i try with unassigned user i should not allow user to log into app. But in my case all the users of  Azure AD are getting access to my app without assigning.

for assigning users i just followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-coreapps-assign-user-azure-portal

And when i am checking individual user profiles there is no application assigned to the users. Is i am missing any app/user level roles while assigning application.

Please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to set the user access in the IAM section of your web app and that will require users to login before using your app.

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate please. Is any reason for this behaviour that without assigning the app in AD how could we access the app, the system should not allow right. Thanks for your time.